# Exporting a column that includes zeroes to csv

Tags: python, export-to-csv

From a large dataset, I am trying to export two columns to csv: 'row_id' and 'accepted'. 'Accepted contains either a 0 or a 1 per row. It is the outcome of a machine learning model.

However, when I check the csv, all of the 0's have disappeared. In other words, if the value of the 'accepted' column is 0 in my data, it is empty in csv. How can I fix this?

I have tried defining the data type like so:

```
my_submission=pd.DataFrame({'row_id':testvalues.row_id,'accepted': solution2}).astype('str')
```

But the output was the same.

My current code:

```
solution2=gbr.predict(testvalues1)
my_submission=pd.DataFrame({'row_id':testvalues.row_id,'accepted': solution2})
my_submission.to_csv('GradientBoosterClassifierSolution.csv', index=False)
```

Current results:

```
row_id, accepted
0,1
1
2
3,1
4
```

Expected results:

```
row_id, accepted
0,1
1,0
2,0
3,1
4,0
```

Comment: Can you run "print(solution2)" so we can see the actual list? Thanks!

Comment: Hi, that returns the following: ````[1 0 0 ... 0 1 1]````   (there are 500k rows)

Comment: I wonder if pandas is interpreting the data as missing. Try printing "df.isnull()". If you get any true values then pandas is missing data and we can deal with that.

Comment: Thank you for your help. I will have time to explore this further on Sunday, I will let you know what the outcome is!

Comment: When I type ````solution2.isnull()```` it shows : 'numpy.ndarray' object has no attribute 'isnull'

Comment: You need "df.isnull()". It's a function for a pandas dataframe.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming theres no data there in your list, add na_rep to your `my_submission.to_csv()` like this

```
my_submission.to_csv('GradientBoosterClassifierSolution.csv', index=False, na_rep='0')
```

That should fill all blanks with 0

Comment: Hi 07logdeT. Ufortunalely, the output remains the same. I am open to any other ideas! Thanks!

Comment: I dug a little deeper... When I check the HTML preview of the csv, it does actually show the desired result. But when I download the file onto my laptop and open the csv, the 0's are gone!

Comment: Did you open the CSV with Excel? Saving it from Excel, even if you didn’t make any changes, can mess CSV files up.

Comment: Are the ‘0s’ missing if you open with npp?

Comment: I did in fact open it with Excel. I will have time to explore this further on Sunday, I will let you know what happened. Thank you for your help so far!

Comment: When I open with npp, it does show zeroes: ````row_id,accepted
0,1
1,0
2,0
3,1
4,0````

Comment: So, to me, I think that the Python is working as intended, just Excel doesn't like the 0s.
I'd have a look at [this](https://xlsxwriter.readthedocs.io/example_pandas_simple.html)? Maybe it might work exporting as a .xlsx instead of a .csv if thats workable for you?